# Are pornographic sculptures part of sanatan dharma?

Tags: history, temple

I stay in a small town in west bengal, india, I found a temple ruin/old temple of very low archeological importance which had orgy position. if you need will upload photos.

My question is since many hindu temples including konark have orgy positions are they part of Santana dharma?

Comment: The kings or whoever in charge, built those temples might not have any Dharmic injunctions to follow while creating erotic statues in the temples. I guess that reflects their personal tastes as you can not find such structures in various other Hindu temples. There is no scriptural injunction (to my knowledge) which will require temples to have such erotic descriptions.

Comment: Your politeness is appreciable. My brain is pointing towards niyog, basis of shiv linga, agni depositing semen in cow, ejaculation of Shiva when mohini appeared, vishnu committing adultery with tulsi. Violation of anusuya.

Comment: @rickross, what you say might be true since grave worship in Islam is prohibited yet ajmer, baghdad, Karbala occupy a large place in so called muslims life

Comment: Not everything that is ancient in Hinduism is correct. Did we not have bad kings and demons? They will keep popping up now and then, and also vanquished. It's possible some of the non-spiritual architects made such figurines. It's also possible that their purpose was to draw laymen in, and later make them spiritual, just as we coat bitter medicines with sugar to get children to eat them

Comment: Probable Duplicate of the [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3428/3869)

Comment: what you say might be true since grave worship in Islam is prohibited yet ajmer, baghdad, Karbala occupy a large place in so called muslims life   -- yes your observation is right. Every person is not expected to perform all their actions strictly according to the religious rules. In fact most people don't care much about them. @Sinner